# Class Pointer Pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Code:

```
Block** blockArray = new Block*[numBlocks];
for (int i=0; i<numBlocks; i++)
{

        fin >> a >> b;
        blockArray[i]->setPosX(a);
        blockArray[i]->setPosY(b);          

}
```

Issue:

When the code hit's blockArray[i]->setPosX(a);
it throws an unhandled exception.  Specifically:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00BF45FB in Nglarsen.Hmwk.3.Assignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xBAADF00D.
```

The only way I've been able to get around this is:

```
Block** blockArray = new Block*[numBlocks];
for (int i=0; i<numBlocks; i++)
{
    blockArray[i]=new Block[1];
    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        fin >> a >> b;
        blockArray[i][j].setPosX(a);
        blockArray[i][j].setPosY(b);            

    }
}
```

But I know there is a better way I'm just forgetting something here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are dereferencing uninitialized pointers in the first case: `blockArray[i]->setPosX(a);`. Why are you using `new` at all? I'd rather recommend using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're allocating an array of pointers, but these pointers point to nothing , you need to iterate over them again , and allocate real objects on them.

```
Block** blockArray = new Block*[numBlocks];

for (int i=0; i<numBlocks; i++)
{
        blockArray[i] = new Block();
        fin >> a >> b;
        blockArray[i]->setPosX(a);
        blockArray[i]->setPosY(b);          

}
```

assuming you want 2-dimenssional array :

```
Block** blockArray = new Block*[numBlocks];

for (int i=0; i<numBlocks; i++)
{
        blockArray[i] = new Block[SIZE];
        for (int j =0 ;j<SIZE;j++){
           blockArray[i][j] = new Block();
           fin >> a >> b;
           blockArray[i][j]->setPosX(a);
           blockArray[i][j]->setPosY(b);  
        }        
}
```

Comment: I see no need to use `new` for this case.

Comment: so how exactly does the object should be created? out of nowhere?

Comment: You see the other answers?

Comment: Thank you, I'm unfamiliar with vector at this point and this solves the problem I have.  I will look into vector as it seems like the solution everyone suggests.

Comment: they showing an alternative way to do so , but they do not tell him how to fix his problem. I might as well suggest him to use external library as a solution.

Comment: How are they not telling him how to fix his problem? Not only do they do what he requires, they don't leak memory and they are more efficient. Everything is in the standard library. Use it.

Comment: they propose an ALTERNATIVE using std::vector. this can be a PROPOSAL not a SOLUTION.

Comment: What's the difference? You are just playing with words. Embrace the standard library. Don't fight it. It's good for you.

Comment: yes. not if you learn pointers in C/C++ and you need to understand how and why things work. not if you program real-time and every chunk of memory/running time is important and many more reasons. he clearly wants to learn how to deal with array of pointers, why not let him understand how to use them? STL is not a substitute for everything. I might as well tell him to program in Javascript. no memory leaks, much simpler syntax and it will solve his problem. why not to embrace Javascript?

Comment: The standard library is not a substitute for everything--but it does provide a tool specifically for the job at hand--and it's a much better tool than the chips of flint you've shown in your answer.

Comment: @DavidHaim With the current standard I see only very very rare number of use cases to use new directly (even for _"real time"_ programming) instead of using standard containers of the smart pointer stuff from `<memory>`.

Comment: I don't argue that the use of std::vector is much better then C-array. I agree 100% with you. I disagree with the fact that an alternative solution without any solution for the CURRENT problem is legit. std::vector is better? ok. go ahead, suggest it. but not before you answer why  the current snippet is not working , especially when it's clear the OP is learning about pointers and he tries to understand memory management

Comment: _"not if you program real-time and every chunk of memory/running time is important"_ Ehm, are you suggesting that manual memory management is somehow faster or more memory efficient than using standard containers? Because that's ludicrous. In fact a simple `std::vector<Block>(numblocks*SIZE)` with wrapped 2D indexing will be _faster_ and take _less_ memory.

Comment: I don't disagree that we should explain the problem with the OP's code before moving on to suggesting complete alternatives, BUT your answer suggests that it's acceptable to write code like this at all. It is not.

Comment: As I stated previously, my solution with vectors is not only easier it IS also more efficient than the solution you propose. Count the number of memory allocations.

Comment: ok. let's argue about vector performance, because that was my point, not the fact that he asked a question about pointers and got an answer about vectors.

Comment: Well, if my opinion counts for anything as the OP, I would say that the argument in and of itself has taught me that I have a long way to go and that vectors are important to learn.  Thanks very much guys.  The problem at hand _was_ solved **and** I've learned that it wasn't the best way to go at it.  Thanks for taking the time to make sure I understood!

Comment: He asked if there was a better way, and the answer is vectors. You brought up the issue of vector performance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Block` fits the requirements for vector, I would do this.

```
std::vector<Block> blocks(numBlocks)
for (auto& block : blocks)
{
    fin >> a >> b;
    block.setPosX(a);
    block.setPosY(b);
}
```

Notice the exquisite lack of memory leaks.

Comment: I will look into vectors, I have yet to learn them.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: On a side note, why did this get down voted so much?  Was it simply a stupid question?

Comment: @Skathix I don't know.

Comment: Alright, well Thank you for all your help then, I'm pretty sure you specifically have helped me in the past.  I'm obviously a student, and sometimes things don't click as well as I wish they would.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious "better way" would be to use a `std::vector` instead. Since you're doing input of your `Block` objects, it's generally cleanest to support that directly by overloading `operator>>` instead of requiring all the code to know about its internal details.

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Block &block) { 
    int a, b;
    is >> a >> b;
    block.setPosX(a);
    block.setPosY(b);
    return is;
}

std::vector<Block> blocks;
blocks.reserve(numBlocks);
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<Block>(fin), numBlocks,std::back_inserter(blocks));
```